# raspberrypi using shell script with if else

Tags: shell, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am trying to switch an LED on or off with my raspberry pi using the gpio-pins.
I wrote this sh-script put it is not working...

```
#!/bin/bash
gpio -g mode 18 out
gpio -g write 18 0
gpio -g write 18 1
gpio -g write 18 0
while true
do
var = read gpio 11
if["$var"=="1"]; then
        gpio -g write 18 1
        echo "Bewegung"
else gpio -g write 18 0
        echo "Keine Bewegung"
fi
done
```

Does anybody see the mistake?

Comment: Please don't paste code as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing the spaces in your `if`-statement. and you should check int variables with `-eq`. Please try out the following. and I'm pretty sure that your assignment `var = read gpio 18` does not work. if you want to make an assignment from the result of a command use `$(<command>)` instead.

```
var=$(echo 1)
if [ $var -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "is one"
else
    echo "is not one"
fi
```

you will find all this information by googling some basic bash-programming tutorials.